# How to Construct Multidimensional Array with Variable Assignment

Tags: arrays, fortran, physics

So I have ran into a problem with array do loops.

I have a list of 976 atom X,Y,Z coordinate arrays. In another text file I have an array with 976 charges for each atom. Additionally, I have arrays for Xo,Yo,Zo with 2,971 points (13x13,x13). What I need to calculate is the distance between the actual X,Y,Z coordinate of the atom and the 2,197 grid points. Orignally what I had done with a calculation with 33 atoms was this.

```
  do i=1,2197
 D1(i) = (((X(1)-Xi(i))**2 + (Y(1)-Yi(i))**2 + (Z(1)-Zi(i))**2)**0.5)*10E-10
 D2(i) = (((X(2)-Xi(i))**2 + (Y(2)-Yi(i))**2 + (Z(2)-Zi(i))**2)**0.5)*10E-10
 D3(i) = (((X(3)-Xi(i))**2 + (Y(3)-Yi(i))**2 + (Z(3) Zi(i))**2)**0.5)*10E-10
 D4(i) = (((X(4)-Xi(i))**2 + (Y(4)-Yi(i))**2 + (Z(4)- 
   Zi(i))**2)**0.5)*10E-10
```

....etc etc

But since now I have 976 atoms, doing this manually would be a nightmare.
My question is this: Since I need to have an array for each atom that will contain 2197 points, is there a way I can generate this without having to write it out manually?

I attempted something like this:

```
do i=1,2197
    Do n=1,976
        DO j=1,976
D(j,i) = (((X(n)-Xi(i))**2 + (Y(n)-Yi(i))**2 + (Z(n)- 
Zi(i))**2)**0.5)*10E-10
        End do
    End Do
Enddo
```

My Logic was to basically compute the 2,197 Distance points for each atom so that they would be stored like this `D(j,i)` which j would represent which atom it is from numbers 1-976 and the variable i would be the 2197 different points calculated by the formula. The idea is to have the 967 atoms in which each atom has 2197 points i can access to use to calculate other things later on. The charges will then be divided by the Distances to find the Voltage potential so basically I would need to be able to call the distances like `D(atom#,charge.)`

Is my logic for this correct or should I approach this problem differently using other array combinations?

Comment: not following all this , but there is no point to the `n` loop here as `d(j,i)` will always just have the value from the `n=976` pass. and will be the same for all `j` as `j` is not in the expression.

Comment: I see what youre saying. What would be a way to for example, tell the program to add up al the 2,197 points for D(1,2197) then for the next 2,197 for the array to be D(2,2197)? Basically a loop that will create a different array D(1+n,i) which will basically store every do loop into a new array in the leftmost subscript?

Comment: your main problem is you don't start with a clear description of what you are trying to do.  What do you mean "add up"? You don't appear to try to add anything in your loop.  If `d(j,i)` is the distance between the `jth` particle and the `ith` grid point, whats `n`?

Comment: I supposed I should have stated my main goal beforehand. Essentially, I had 976 atoms each with XYZ coordinates and charges. I needed to calculate the distance between the actual atom XYZ coordinates and the grid points(in this case I made a 13x13x13 grid therefore 2197 unique points). The actual calculation is simple for a few atoms because I just create D1(2197) and D1 refers to the 2197 unique distances generated by the distance formula for ATOM1. For atom 2 i would do D2(2197)  and D3 would have 2197 points etc. The aim was to construct a loop that would automatically number D1-D976 auto.

Comment: -automatically without me having to state D1(i) = distance formula, D2(i)=distance ... D976(i) = distance formula. I could have done it manually and assigned each atom its array but I wanted to know if there was a way to do it automatically through a do loop, and it turns out there was. Now the only issue I am having is having the program read the data correct from the text file but i guess I will figure it out soon.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather difficult to understand, at least for me, but assuming that this is not a homework question and that you are solely a Fortran enthusiast or new developer, here is a non-object-oriented but modern efficient solution:

```
program confusingQuestion

use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: int32,real64
implicit none

integer(int32), parameter :: nAtom = 976
integer(int32), parameter :: nGrid = 2197
real(real64)              :: AtomCrd(3,nAtom), AtomCharge(nAtom)
real(real64)              :: GridCrd(3,nGrid), Atom2GridDistance(nGrid,nAtom)
integer(int32)            :: iAtom,iGrid

! for demonstration purposes, I assign random values to variables
call random_number(AtomCrd)
call random_number(GridCrd)
call random_number(AtomCharge)

do concurrent (iAtom = 1:nAtom,iGrid=1:nGrid)
  Atom2GridDistance(iGrid,iAtom) = norm2( AtomCrd(:,iAtom)-GridCrd(:,iGrid) )
end do

! print a sample:
write(*,'(*(g0.4,","))') Atom2GridDistance(:,1) ! print distances for the first atom
end program confusingQuestion
```

Note that I have used `do concurrent` construct here purposefully. Unlike the regular do-loop which is executed serially, one after the other, `do concurrent` tells the compiler that all the element-wise calculations in the loop are independent of each other and that they can be calculated concurrently. Therefore, depending on your compiler, this code may be executed in parallel, which will increase the speed of your code.

Also, there is no need to implement L2-norm manually in your code. Fortran already has more than one methods for calculating the L2-norm, one of which is `norm2 (x [ , dim ] )`, which returns the L2-norm of a real array x; with the result being a real scalar of the same kind as x.
Note that you will need a Fortran 2008 compiler, to compile this code. Here is an online 2008 compiler with which you could try the code https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_fortran_online.php

Just keep in mind that in order to let compiler auto-parallelize the concurrent loop for you, you will very likely need to compile your code with O2 or better yet, O3 optimization flags, as well as auto-parallelization flags (for example in Intel's ifort). I am not sure about the status of `do concurrent` in GNU gfortran. However, I have seen noticeable performance difference with it when using Intel ifort compiler. Here is a related but old thread on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25860047/2088694

Comment: Wow! I would have never thought of going this route. It was not a homework question, I am actually a Biochemistry Undergraduate (not a programmer whatsoever haha). I just wanted to find a way to speed up my calculations for large protein systems (voltage-gated potassium and sodium channels to be exact. I know all the calculations that need to be done, I am just not good at figuring out how to code it properly. Nonetheless, the do concurrent is something I did not even know about, Im sure it will speed up the calculations instead of going my old-dinosaur age route. Thank you for the insight!

Comment: glad to hear the information was useful. I have added a new paragraph on this topic to the answer above. cheers.

Comment: just to note there is nothing fundamentally wrong with a basic `do` loop.  As a newbie you really should learn how to write one correctly.